# The bundle could not be resolved in RCP-RAP application

Tags: eclipse, plugins, bundle, rcp

I have a RCP application which constitutes of a number of plugins. And now, I try to develop RAP application which uses my old plugins. My RAP has a dependency of one old plugin. I created my own  target platform and I added RAP sdk and other many eclipse platform libraries. When I run my RAP application, I get this exception. Do you have any idea to solve that?  Depended plugin uses "org.eclipse.ui" package.

org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Require-Bundle: org.unicase.link; bundle-version="1.0.0"
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolverError(AbstractBundle.java:1313)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolutionFailureException(AbstractBundle.java:1297)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:319)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:370)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1069)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:554)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:461)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:246)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:442)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:227)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:337)

2009-12-02 01:13:23.625::WARN:  ERROR:  /rap
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An entry point named 'hello' does not exist.
 at org.eclipse.rwt.internal.lifecycle.EntryPointManager.createUI(EntryPointManager.java:77)
 at org.eclipse.rwt.internal.lifecycle.RWTLifeCycle.createUI(RWTLifeCycle.java:227)
 at org.eclipse.rwt.internal.lifecycle.RWTLifeCycle$UIThreadController.run(RWTLifeCycle.java:115)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
 at org.eclipse.rwt.internal.lifecycle.UIThread.run(UIThread.java:80)

Answer (score 1):

It's failing because it can't load the org.unicase.link bundle.  And the reason that it can't load that is probably a missing dependency in that bundle.  So look in the manifest for that plugin and look at all of the dependent plugins and make sure they are all there.  It should also have a list for the plugins that were not loaded for some reason in the log.  One thing you can do is make all of the dependencies in the org.unicase.link bundle optional, which should get you further along.